# Python: Why can't I add leading zeros?

Tags: python

```
number = 12345677
number_str = str(number)
zero_filled_number = number_str.zfill(2)

print(zero_filled_number)

string = "hi"
zero_filled_string = string.zfill(2)

print(zero_filled_string)

print(f'{number:05d}')
```

I cannot add leading zeros to my number. I have tried string formatting and `zfill()`but no leading zeros are added. Why?

The output is:

```
12345677
hi
12345677
```

Comment: try this number_str.zfill(10)   as you need to add 2 zeros and you have 8 in the int

Answer (score 1):

Because `zfill(x)` adds zeros until the string is `x` chars long. In your case, it's better to just add zeros manually : `'00'+string`

Answer (score 1):

`zfill()` will add zeros to the beginning of your string, in case it has not the length you pass as a parameter. The parameter `len` is in your case 2.

But in your case the string has a length of more than 2, so it will never work.

Minimal example:

```
st = "123"
str_fill = st.zfill(4)
print(str_fill)
```

So str_fill will be `0123`.